# if statement to create new column pandas for string variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, if-statement

With this dataframe, I would like to create another column that is based on the values of the first column.

```
data = {'item_name':  ['apple', 'banana', 'cherries', 'duck','chicken','pork']}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['item_name'])
```

```
Expected df:
item_name  item_type
apple      fruit
banana     fruit
cherries   fruit
duck       meat
beef       meat
pork       meat
```

Code that I tried:

```
def item_type(item_name):
   if df['item_name'] is in ['apple','banana','cherries']:
       df['item_type']=='fruit'
   else:
       df['item_type']=='meat'

df = df.apply(item_type)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.where`:

```
df['item_type'] = np.where(df['item_name'].isin(['apple','banana','cherries']),
                           'fruit', 'meat')
```

Output:

```
  item_name item_type
0     apple     fruit
1    banana     fruit
2  cherries     fruit
3      duck      meat
4   chicken      meat
5      pork      meat
```